# Add-Migration gives error after adding dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework-core

After adding a dependency injection to my Azure Function project I can't run "Add-Migration" & "Update Database" anymore.

EntityFrameWorkCore(.Design, .SqlServer, .Tools)-packages are on v6.0.0

My DbContext:

```
    public class ContosoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ContosoTable> Contoso { get; set; }
    public ContosoDbContext(DbContextOptions<ContosoDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

My Startup:

```
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        var connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStringToDb"];

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContosoDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
        );
    }
}
```

Also read about to use a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to get it to work after adding Dependency Injection:

```
    public class ContosoDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ContosoDbContext>
{
    public ContosoDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ContosoDbContext>();

        var connectionString = configuration["ConnectionStringToDb"];
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ContosoDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Somehow I get this error when running `Add-Migration`:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Do you have access to InnerExpeption? Exception with this message is thrown, when you raise an event, and one of attached delegates throws an exception, or when ou call method vie reflection. So it does not provide too much information.

Comment: I just found out I can access the exceptions with -verbose. Like this: "Add-Migration Initial -verbose". Comes out my connectionString was throwing an NullReferenceException..

Also found the solution see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Startup class for Azure Functions, the configuration is loaded differently than how it would be in a typical ASP.NET Core app. The Azure Functions SDK automatically handles the "Values" nesting within local.settings.json when building the configuration for my case.

As a result, when I use `configuration["AzureSettings:Database"]` in my Startup class, it works correctly.

However, if you are working with EF design-time tools like migrations, they're not aware of this special behavior of Azure Functions. This is why you are supposed to use the "Values" nesting in your DesignTimeDbContextFactory.

So in this case you need to use `configuration["Values:AzureSettings:Database"]`